# How to optimize BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: android, optimization, adapter, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

this is the getChildView method from my BaseExpandableListAdapter class,the code works, but I wanna know is there a way to optimize my code, like using viewholder or sth else.
as you can see, the child views are using different layouts;

```
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Base b= (Base) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (b instanceof SubClassA) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a, null);   
    }

    if (b instanceof SubClassB)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b, null);
    }

            //..

    return convertView;
}
```